# Есть ли метод в c# указывающий наличие символа в массиве символов?

Tags: c#

Существует ли метод в c# который, возвращает значение, указывающее, содержит ли определенный массив символов указанный символ?

Comment: Ещё IndexOf можно использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел, вот: `char[].Contains(char)`